# Multiarch on Debian 9 breaks my system

Tags: debian

I have a fresh, brand new installation of Debian 9.

After installation was completed, I installed the NVIDIA proprietary driver and everything worked fine.

The problem started when I tried to install Steam, because out of the box, it doesn't work on Debian 64 bit; I have to install some packages like:

```
apt install libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386
```

Which only works with:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

The problem is after that package is installed, because now I have some broken dependencies and I cannot use `apt` correctly, LibreOffice and Nvidia are uninstalled.

At the end, my whole system is broken and the only way for me to fix it is with a new fresh installation.

I have also tried `aptitude` and the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gdebi](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gdebi).

`gdebi` installs a `.deb` package and its dependencies. To use it run:

```
sudo gdebi package.deb
```

You can install `gdebi` with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

See [`man gdebi`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/gdebi) for a full list of options.

`gdebi` is the command line equivalent to the graphical tool of the same name , the command for the graphical tool is `gdebi-gtk` and has similar functionality:

[image: gdebi]